Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Mview\View\SubscriptionStatementPostprocessorInterface#0
After upgrade magento 2.4.3-p1 to magento 2.4.7-p1, the issue is occured after run the command php magento/bin setup:upgrade.
Issue:
Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Mview\View\SubscriptionStatementPostprocessorInterface#0
Even I have checked the custom triggers in database, but no custom triggers.
Thanks for advance.

check if the Magento_Csp Module is enabled?

i thing some module is disabled which interface class Is used somewhere

I had removed the vendor folders all files and keep only .htaccess. after that composer update command run and then run php magento/bin setup:upgrade. finally issue fixed

Check if have any module causing conflits, try disable custom modules. If the issue is resolved, re-enable the modules one by one to find the conflit.
U can try regenerate dependency too.
rm -rf generated/metadata/* generated/code/*
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:upgrade

If have error yet u may enable debug login in .env
 'db' => [
    'connection' => [
        'default' => [
            'logging' => [
                'enabled' => true,
            ],
        ],
    ],

    'dev' => [
        'debug' => [
           'debug_logging' => 1,
         ],
    ]


Hey, Do you use redis cache? If yes please purge the cache and run the command, Thank You!
